# output nested list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
 a = [[0,11], [1,12], [3,14], [5,16],[7,18]]
```

I want to create a new list `b` that takes all elements satistying

```
 a[:,0] > 3
```

and prepend the index in `a` of the selected nested list.
So b shoudl look like:

```
b = [[3, 5, 16],[4, 7,18]]
```

With:

```
b = [points, points in a if points[0]>3]
```

will output `b = [[5, 16],[7,18]]` with the index, and

```
b = [[index, points], index, points in enumerate(a) if points[0]>3]
```

shows an error. How can I generated `b` using list comprehension?

Comment: "a[:,0] > 3" - that's NumPy syntax. Are you using NumPy? What's with the lists?

Comment: Indeed, I am using numpy. For my application,  a is in fact a np.array, but I did not see any difference in using a as type array or list, so for simplification I left it as a list above.

Comment: There are pretty major differences in efficiency and the semantics of a number of operations. If you're using NumPy, you should always make that clear in your question, as the best answer for NumPy arrays is usually different from the best answer for lists.

Comment: OK, I'll make sure to clarify in future questions. if a is converted to =>  np.array(a). Would there be an approach different than those provided by Kasramvd?

Comment: The `[i] + points` thing wouldn't work for a NumPy array, and the other solutions would likely be slow. I've posted a NumPy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tuple of throwaway variables for holding the nested lists items:

```
>>> [[i,j,k] for i,(j,k) in enumerate(a) if j>3]
[[3, 5, 16], [4, 7, 18]]
```

Or as a more comprehensive approach for lists with more items you can use following list comprehension:

```
>>> [[i] + points for i, points in enumerate(a) if points[0]>3]
[[3, 5, 16], [4, 7, 18]]
```

Python 3 version using unpacking assignment:

```
>>> [[i, first] + rest for i,(first, *rest) in enumerate(a) if first>3]
[[3, 5, 16], [4, 7, 18]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd approach is very elegant (no need to break points into  elements j,k.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is a NumPy array (which it seems to be in your actual use case), you could do the following:

```
# One of the rare cases when numpy.where isn't superfluous.
indices = numpy.where(a[:, 0] > 3)[0]

index_column = indices[:, None]
selected_rows = a[indices]

b = numpy.hstack([index_column, selected_rows])
```

Or with less intermediate variables:

```
indices = numpy.where(a[:, 0] > 3)[0]
b = numpy.hstack([indices[:, None], a[indices]])
```

For large sizes of `a`, this will probably outperform solutions based on `enumerate` or other Python-level iteration techniques.

Comment: Thanks 'user2357112', that works very well (Note that, a ']' is missing in last line). BTW, this might be outside the scope of the post: but how to determine whether a built-in function uses iteration. In the case of enumerate it is obvious, but how do you know that np.where() is not iterative?

Comment: @JMarc: Thanks for the typo correction. `np.where` is iterative, but it doesn't go through the overhead of Python bytecode interpretation or the Python iterator protocol. Generally, if you see the word `for` in your code, that part of your code is using Python-level iteration. NumPy routines given NumPy arrays as input will generally bypass that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I started answering this question but other people posted before I could, so here's another way to do it (without list comprehensions but still pretty cryptic):

`map(lambda y: [y[0]] + y[1], filter(lambda x: x[1][0] > 3, enumerate(a)))`